# What are the security measures to be taken before launching a site with credit card payments?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, credit-card, threat-mitigation, threats, payment-gateway

We just completed functionality testing of our new e-commerce site and going to launch.We are accepting credit card payments. I'm really concerned about it's security.What are the precautions to be taken? I'm not so good at web security. Please advice.

Comment: I'm glad that you are at least concerned about security, but for the love of all that is holy, **HIRE A PROFESSIONAL SECURITY CONSULTANT**. I'm not trying to offend you or be rude, but there is no other practical alternative if your going to be handling other peoples money.

Comment: Use an existing payment service provider to handle taking card details; keep them out of your own systems at all costs.

Comment: > Use an existing payment service provider +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah.... you don't do something like that yourself when "*I'm not so good at web security.*" Have a look at [PCI-DSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard) and the horrible horrible things that you can be liable for if you don't do things properly.

Instead, you should use something like [Authorized.net](http://www.authorize.net/) to take care of handling that part for you.

Also, I *really* hope that you are using an existing e-commerce solution instead of writing your own. The amount of things that you can screw up when you have no idea what you are doing is so scary it's not even funny.